# Spring URL protocol doesn't like LDAPS?

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I have configured the following beans in my application context:

```
<bean id="bindConnectionPool" parent="abstractConnectionPool"
    p:connectionFactory-ref="bindConnectionFactory" />

<bean id="bindConnectionFactory"
    class="org.ldaptive.DefaultConnectionFactory"
    p:connectionConfig-ref="bindConnectionConfig" />

<bean id="bindConnectionConfig" parent="abstractConnectionConfig" />

<bean id="abstractConnectionConfig" abstract="true"
    class="org.ldaptive.ConnectionConfig"
    p:ldapUrl="ldaps://myldap.example.com:636"
    p:connectTimeout="3000"
    p:useStartTLS="true"
    p:sslConfig-ref="sslConfig" />

<!-- EDIT/UPDATE: -->
<bean id="sslConfig" class="org.ldaptive.ssl.SslConfig">
    <property name="credentialConfig">
        <bean class="org.ldaptive.ssl.X509CredentialConfig"
            p:trustCertificates="mycert" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

When I deploy the WAR to Tomcat I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
    with name ‘bindConnectionPool’ defined in ServletContext resource
    [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception
    is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path must start with either classpath: or file:
```

What do I need to change the LDAPS-based URL to? Neither `file:` nor `classpath:` make sense here...thoughts?

Or, is `ldapUrl` a red herring, and is there some other path defined on this `bindConnectionPool` bean that isn't configured right? Oh, and obviously, can't post the LDAP server's actual name for security reasons (`myldap.example.com` is a different value).

Comment: I think you might be misinterpreting the error (*"Invocation of init method failed"*). Can you post a bit more from the stack trace of that IllegalArgumentException? This might not be connected to `ldapUrl` at all...

Comment: Just checked Ldaptive Spring tutorial to see where your problem might be coming from... and the real issue will be probably in `bindConnectionPool` dependencies, namely `credentialConfig` and its `keyStore` property. http://www.ldaptive.org/docs/guide/spring

Comment: Thanks @PavelHoral (+2) - please see my update that includes the `credentialConfig` bean. Now, this may be **very** important: this app is deployed to Tomcat. In the keystore that Tomcat uses, I have a key with an alias of `mycert`. I'm wondering if the `X509CredentialConfig#trustCertificates` property (above) needs to be a different value than `mycert`. I just *figured* that the `trustCertificates` name would match up to the key alias to use...thoughts?

Comment: `trustCertificates` is supposed to have location of X509 certificate location (PEM / DER / PKCS7) - http://www.ldaptive.org/docs/guide/connections . There is no connection to Tomcat's truststore. So I guess the `IllegalArgumentException` is being actually thrown by *X509CredentialConfig* (that is why I asked for the stack trace ;)).

Comment: Never forget to check the stack trace ;): https://code.google.com/p/vt-middleware/source/browse/ldaptive/core/trunk/src/main/java/org/ldaptive/LdapUtils.java#399 -> https://code.google.com/p/vt-middleware/source/browse/ldaptive/core/trunk/src/main/java/org/ldaptive/ssl/AbstractCredentialReader.java#48 -> https://code.google.com/p/vt-middleware/source/browse/ldaptive/core/trunk/src/main/java/org/ldaptive/ssl/X509CredentialConfig.java#129 It would save you a lot of time debugging the problem.